# npm deletes on its own after closing the ubuntu terminal?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, virtualbox, nvm

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial on VirtualBox. The problem is that once I install npm using the command:

```
nvm install v8.1
```

then it recognizes commands like `npm`.
But if I close this particular session of terminal and reopen it again, then it fails to recognize `npm` command. So everytime I need to use npm, I have to reinstall it for that particular session of terminal. And when I reinstall it using `nvm install v8.1`, It says,

```
v8.1.4 is already installed.
Now using node v8.1.4 (npm v5.0.3)
```

But now it recognizes npm command. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When node is installed via `nvm`, it's actually expected that you would type `nvm use 8` before using node. You shouldn't have to re-install it (and, based on your output, it looks like you didn't).

If you want to default to node v8, you can do that by typing:

```
nvm alias default 8.1
```

Note that you may be missing the appropriate .bashrc entry (in your ~/.bashrc file) that loads nvm when your terminal starts up. It should look something like this:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```